# Ionic ios app Build failed MainController.xib

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Sometimes when i try to build my ios project on xcode i get the following error

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileXIB ProjectName/Classes/MainViewController.xib

Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/ritesh/Documents/Projects/test-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,ProjectName.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,ProjectName,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/ritesh/Documents/Projects/test-app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/ritesh/Documents/Projects/test-app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/ritesh/Documents/Projects/test-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/ritesh/Documents/Projects/test-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I read this bolog post and while his suggestion makes sense but I dont have a duplicate of the file which he said i should see when i open my .pbxproj file.

https://medium.com/@_qzapaia/cordova-ionic-ios-build-error-697a7ec5b46#.snruarnmz

if i build my project for the second time, it builds properly so im not sure what is causing this occasionally. Any clues from anyone?

Cheers

Comment: I think it's a bug on xcode, apple broke something with the update, I've been getting this on native projects too

Comment: I had same problem. I manually "rm plugins/ios.json", then "cordova platform rm ios" (probably redundant), then "cordova platform add ios". Changed permissions and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Run (this will remove the old ionic ios platform)

```
sudo ionic platform rm ios
```

Then (this will install a new platform with privileges)

```
sudo ionic platform add ios
```

Then build your code ios/android

```
ionic build ios
ionic build android
```

This fixed it for me!

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same problem for like three days, and I just solved it for myself. My issue was that I was using Xcode 7.1, and apparently there's something about that version that was causing the compiler issue.

Solution:

- I uninstalled Xcode 7.1 by deleting the app from my Applications folder.
- I went to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and downloaded Xcode 6.4 instead.

After downgrading to Xcode 6.4, I was able to build for ios without an issue.

Comment: u cant be downgrading because then ur app wont be built on ios9 so it will still break upon pushing to app store. u better upgrade it back and find a solution.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know. I'm new to mobile development, so that was an issue I did not anticipate. But it seems to be an Xcode issue; not sure how else I would go about solving it.